# Winforms GroupBox.AutoSize not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` with a `GroupBox` in the first row. 
Based on user interaction on the form, a `Panel` within the `GroupBox` has its `Visibility` set from `true` or `false`.

When this `Visibility` is `false`, I want the `GroupBox` to resize the contents (move them up to replace the empty space).

I have the `AutoSize` property `= true`, and `AutoSizeMode` set to `GrowAndShrink`.
The `GroupBox` is docked within the row, which is set to `AutoSize` within the `TableLayoutPanel`. 
I have even tried setting the same `AutoSize` properties in the TLP itself, but nothing gets adjusted when the visibility of that control is changed.

Comment: The difference is that I'm trying to hide the visibility of one control within the GroupBox containing other controls, which itself is docked in the row set to Auto. When the visibility changes to False, I want the GroupBox contents to themselves shift up to replace the empty space. I guess I could do another TLP within the groupbox, but then what is the point of the AutoSize property within  GroupBox?